# PHP appends localhost to out-going email

Tags: php

Here's a PHP code that I'm using to test email sending for one of my forms. Although it works well, but for some reason it appends 
@localhost.mydomain.com to the sender email address. Here's an example:

```
From: James <james.bond@hotmail.com@localhost.mydomain.com>
```

Here's the full code below.

```
<?php
       $email = sqlEscape($_POST['email']);
       $name  = sqlEscape($_POST['name']);
       $to = 'me@yahoo.com';
       $subject = 'Email From website';
       $message = 'The message here';

        $headers = 'From: "'.$name.'" <"'.$email.'">' . "\n";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){                            

            echo('Message sent successfully');                      
        }else{
            echo('<a href="contact.php">Click here</a> to try again.');     
        }
?>
```

Is there a way to make it not to append it? Thanks

Comment: have you tried without `sqlEscape()`?

Comment: Why would you sqlEscape something that is not going into any form of sql

Comment: What is the value of `$email` before you send it? What SMTP service are you using?  Your SMTP server may have a policy of appending the real outbound domain to a from header of a relaying address.

Comment: What mail server are you using?

Comment: what is the value of `$_POST['email']` ?

Comment: In other words, since you are taking the From address from POST, the server may refuse to deliver a message on behalf of someone else without appending its own domain (though I have never seen one append a second @ as this did.

Comment: I'm using Postfix on Ubuntu server. BTW, the sqlEscape is used for inserting those values into my database. I just removed the database bit of the code.

Comment: Accepting a from address from POST leaves you [vulnerable to mail header injection](http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection) (by which your form can be used as a spam relay).

Comment: PHP is likely not responsible for this.  Examine your Postfix configuration. I'm not certain which directive is used to append a domain, but serverfault.com may be able to help.

Comment: I'd put the From line in the body of the email message, and hardwire a generic email address as the From field. It's slightly less convenient than this way, but it sidesteps a lot of problems.

Comment: Thanks guys for your amazing tip - especially to @Michael for the link. I will now hardcode the From address. Cheers again :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`ini_set(sendmail_from,$_POST['email']);`?

Add this line before the mail() function call.

Comment: That's for Windows only. OP is on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that when I posted. I found another forum post: http://serverfault.com/questions/119105/setup-ubuntu-server-to-send-mail#answer-289290